# What are scale degrees?

Tags: theory, scales, band

I heard my band teacher talking about "scale degrees" and do not understand what he means.

Comment: [Scale degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28music%29)

Comment: If you don't understand what your teacher means, the usual thing to do is ask them.

Comment: What research have you done, apart from posting the question here? At very least, ask teacher and peers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you know that music notes named cdefg or doremifasol are ascending like a scale (meaning a ladder or a stair) so a degrees is a single step of this scale.

But the band leader might also have meant the triads of thirds that are built on each degree: e.g. domiso or ceg. (If you skip always one note you get thirds and fifths like 135. You can play the tones 1-3-5 from any degree of an instrument. On the piano the degrees are the keys in the scale of C major the white keys.

Study the pattern of triads (chords) on a piano keyboard and you will get the idea of scales and degrees. If we play the row of white keys we get the C major scale. Starting with C = I ,D =II,E=III  ...

As we've seen the scale degree can mean the single tone of each step, but also the chord  on each step of this ladder.

Comment: I've never heard 'degree' used to mean a chord.   We could talk of 'the triad on the 3rd degree of C major' (which would be E, G, B-  E minor) but the 'degree' is the note not the chord.

Comment: *In Schenkerian analysis, "scale degree" (or "scale step") translates Schenker's German Stufe, denoting "a chord having gained structural significance" (see Schenkerian analysis#Harmony).* see your posted wiki link.

Comment: Yeah.  But we're talking about music.  Getting into Schenkerian is like citing Leviticus in a discussion of morals :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are 7 different notes in (most) scales.   (The 8th is a repeat of the first.)

C, D, E, F, G, A, B.   The seven notes of C major scale.  Or the 1st, 2nd etc.  degrees of the scale.  That is what 'degree' means.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(music)